# Firewall (Firebox - WatchGuard) configuration for exchange server 2016

Tags: firewall, exchange

I have installed Exchange Server 2016 and ready to use. My provider has done relative changes to public domains.

Below picture shows my network topology

[image]

`x.x.x.x` is my static IP address

What changes must I do to the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331973(v=exchg.160).aspx) and act on it.